# Firebase cloud functions unreasonably slow

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

We run a Firebase application using onCall heavily. The problem, however, is that the functions answer unreasonably slow. Simple functions take 4 seconds to answer even after repeat invocations.

Som things we already take into account:

- Coldstart: We are aware that Firebase cloud functions can be slow when they have not been run for a while. We still have the problem after repeat invocations.
- Large result set: The responses are slow even when Firestore result sets are empty.
- CORS OPTIONS preflight also take unreasonably long to response (often 4-8 seconds)
- We are on a Blaze plan.
- The same call with the same result size yield very different

In the following picture, none of the calls are other than simple Object retrievals. None of the documents in the result sets trigger further checks. Still we have more than 8 seconds for retrieving 66KB woth of data.

[image]

Following image are merely for preflight requests. We do not expect those to even hit our code. Is that wrongly assumed?

[image]

Lastly, it should be mentioned that we are based in the EU and that the servers are located in the US. But we don't think that this explains 4 second response times.

Comment: The most likely situation is the quality of the network between continents.  Benchmarks that don't take network quality into account aren't really all that actionable.

Comment: @DougStevenson would you suggest that moving to project to the EU would give us consistent sub second response times? I would expect a few call to reach a couple of secs because of the network, but not consistently roughly half of them

Comment: Moving everything to a different region would definitely be something to try next, just to get a sense of how that affects the end user experience from various locations and networks that you have access to.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly the same problem with callable functions to retrieve `customClaims`, after using stack drive to monitor the function for several days I concluded it is caused by cold starts.

[image]

Take a look those in orange, it seems when the same instance is warm it works like charm as you mention on your case, as soon as, it gets cold (after around 15 mins), we find the peeks again.

This also brings other challenges... take a look at this.

[image]

The fact that we are using an instance at the same time, it doesn't mean everyone will use that instance (during that time), I've found when several users call the function during the same time and it's cold, it spins up more instances (up to 6 on the same).

I haven't nailed the right formula to decrease those times while keeping a decent amount of security around but [I've documented a few findings](https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/scaling-google-cloud-functions-to-300-instances-in-one-minute), maybe they might help (they are on background functions only) I will make the same tests on callable functions soon,